# Apple's Xcode developing tutorial: "Thread 1: Fatal error: The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell."

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to Xcode/swift and have been trying for 2 weeks to accomplish the Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift) tutorial from apple to build the 'FoodTracker' app. Thanks to SOF i've managed to come to the last page but now i'm stuck on the error in the title.

My goal is to have the app functioning 100%. I've even copied the page with code to see if I can make it work this way but to no avail. The app was functioning properly until this point. The last step I took was to have the app put three examples in a list (the first page of the app). The second page (where the user can input information) isn't linked to the first Table View Controller but there are 3 example products that should be displayed in the list by now.

```swift
import UIKit

class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: Properties

    var meals = [Meal]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load the sample data.
        loadSampleMeals()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: - Table view data source


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return meals.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"

        **guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MealTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")**
        }

        // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
        let meal = meals[indexPath.row]

        cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name
        cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo
        cell.ratingControl.rating = meal.rating

        return cell
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    //MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    //MARK: Private Methods

    private func loadSampleMeals() {

        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "meal1")
        let photo2 = UIImage(named: "meal2")
        let photo3 = UIImage(named: "meal3")

        guard let meal1 = Meal(name: "Caprese Salad", photo: photo1, rating: 4) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal1")
        }

        guard let meal2 = Meal(name: "Chicken and Potatoes", photo: photo2, rating: 5) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
        }

        guard let meal3 = Meal(name: "Pasta with Meatballs", photo: photo3, rating: 3) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
        }

        meals += [meal1, meal2, meal3]
    }

}
```

Comment: I've marked the error BOLD in the code above but I can't see it so here is the faulty line:

guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MealTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")

Comment: Did you set the cell in your storyboard to `MealTableViewCell` ?

Comment: Hello Koen, thank you for replying. So in the table View controller is a Table View which contains the cell. When the cell is selected the Identifier in the attribute inspecter says MealTableViewCell. Is that correct?

Comment: You need to set it in the Attributes inspector and in the Identity inspector. It is easy to forget one of them.

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thank you very much Koen! I've got another question but I think it's not related. Should I open an other thread of post it here?

Comment: Yes, post a new question. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

When using a custom `UITableViewCell`, make sure to use your custom class name in your storyboard, in your case `MealTableViewCell`. You need to do this in two places:

1. In the Attributes inspector -> set the Identifier field to `MealTableViewCell`
2. In the Identity inspector -> set the Class field to `MealTableViewCell`

It's easy to forget one of them.